# Cannot create TypedQuery for query with more than one return using requested result type, despite having correct DTO

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I have gone through other similar questions on this topic and found that my setup is correct (at least confirms to what others had suggested in the past).

I do have a dedicated AllRecordsDTO for the purpose of this query, and it does have all the necessary fields for successful mapping of the query result.

**AllRecordsDTO.java :**

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@ToString
public class AllRecordsDTO {

    @Getter
    @Setter
    private String recordName;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    private String recordTypeName;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    private String statusName;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    private String createdByUserId;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    private String createdDateTime;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    private String lastChangedByUserId;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    private String lastChangedDateTime;

}
```

The **allRecordsQuery** query

```sql
    select r.recordName,
       rt.recordTypeName,
       s.name,
       usi.userId,
       r.createdDateTime,
       usi1.userId,
       r.lastChangedDateTime
from Record r
         left join Section s on s.id = r.statusId
         left join UniqueSecurityIdentifier usi on usi.id = r.createdByUserId
         left join RecordType rt on rt.id = r.recordTypeId
         left join UniqueSecurityIdentifier usi1 on usi1.id = r.lastChangedByUserId
```

The line that throws the exception :

```
Query<AllRecordsDTO> createdQuery = statelessSession.createQuery(allRecordsQuery, AllRecordssDTO.class);
```

All the Entity fields used in the query above are String (even the date fields are String in the above entities).

I am not sure what could have gone wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying is not possible with JPA.

You habe to use the Constructor Expression.

```
select NEW <packagename>.AllRecordsDTO(r.recordName,
       rt.recordTypeName,
       s.name,
       usi.userId,
       r.createdDateTime,
       usi1.userId,
       r.lastChangedDateTime)
from Record r
         left join Section s on s.id = r.statusId
         left join UniqueSecurityIdentifier usi on usi.id = r.createdByUserId
         left join RecordType rt on rt.id = r.recordTypeId
         left join UniqueSecurityIdentifier usi1 on usi1.id = r.lastChangedByUserId
```

Please also checkout the Hibernate documentation: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#hql-select-clause

Comment: Thank you so much. This works. But I didn't mention one more detail (for the sake of brevity, thinking it might be just a case related to the query syntax). My bad. Actually I had been trying to use this in the context of ScrollableResults. I'll edit the question to add more  context.

Comment: I am going to create a separate post (regarding the ScrollableResults issue) referencing this OP. I believe I'll be doing justice to the effort and time invested by the answerer(s) . As far as the original question is concerned it stands answered. I'll edit this post to remove the edits. Thank you.